# Add value from nested array into div classname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm still new with React, JavaScript and now I encountered a problem.

Is somehow possible to add value from nested array into **"parent" div class**?

I have posts and each post has categories array. I need to loop through posts and show title, text.

I used **.map** to loop through posts and show title and text. But how can I loop through categories, get the name value and add it into div class?

**Data:**

```
const posts = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'My awesome post title',
    text: 'Hello this is the text',
    categories: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'category1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'category2'
    }],
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'My post title 2',
    text: 'Another post is here',
    categories: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'category3',
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'category10'
    }]
}];
```

**I need this:**

```
<div className="posts">
    <div className="post category1 category2">
        <h2>My awesome post title<h2>
        <p>Hello this is the text</p>
    </div>

    <div className="post category3 category10">
        <h2>My post title 2<h2>
        <p>Another post is here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: you've forgotten to copy-paste your javascript showing your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the entire set of object properties that correspond to post data as a bunch of `<Post />` component props, you may transform one of those props and throw it as JSX element attribute, using common JavaScript injection syntax (`{}`):

```
const Post = ({categories,title,text}) => {
  const className = ['post', ...categories.map(({name}) => name)].join(' ')
  return (
      <div {...{className}}>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
  )
}
```

You may find the quick demo below (inspect it with DevTools to make sure all the class names are applied properly):

```js
//dependencies
const { render } = ReactDOM

//source data
const posts = [{id:1,title:'My awesome post title',text:'Hello this is the text',categories:[{id:1,name:'category1'},{id:2,name:'category2'}],},{id:2,title:'My post title 2',text:'Another post is here',categories:[{id:1,name:'category3',},{id:2,name:'category10'}]}]

//post component
const Post = ({categories,title,text}) => {
  const className = ['post', ...categories.map(({name}) => name)].join(' ')
  return (
      <div {...{className}}>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
  )
}

//post feed component
const PostFeed = ({postsData}) => (
  <div className="posts">
    {postsData.map(({categories,title,text},key) => <Post {...{key,categories,title,text}} />)}
  </div>
)

//render
render(
  <PostFeed postsData={posts} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. It helped me a lot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you could approach this problem. One way would be to use `map` to extract the category names into an array, then `join` the array with a space, like so:

```js
let categories = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'category1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'category2'
    }];
    
const classList = categories.map( cat => cat.name ).join(" ");

console.log( classList );
```

Another, more complicated though *perhaps* [more efficient](https://gist.github.com/scriptype/a80c1e0e7282af6742adbbea4dfdf50a) approach would be to use `reduce`:

```js
let categories = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'category1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'category2'
    }];
    
const classList = categories.reduce( ( acc, cat ) => { acc += ` ${cat.name}`; return acc; }, "" );

console.log( classList );
```

Since you haven't posted in your existing code, I don't know how exactly you'd integrate these solutions into your existing approach, but they shouldn't be too hard to adapt.